# Mysterious EntityTypes in my reverse-engineered DbContext, without keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I had an old Database-first EF 6.1 model which I wanted to convert to Code-first.

I have used [EF Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EntityFrameworkTeam.EntityFrameworkPowerToolsBeta4) from Microsoft in order to perform the reverse engineering. But since I had already made a *few* tweaks I reused the old `.cs` files that were generated by the T4 template of DB-first. Those tweaks included (as far as I remember):

- Renaming classes to a readable name, keeping table name the original. E.g. I have a table `sottogruppi` which mapped to `sottogruppi` class and `sottogruppi` DbSet. I renamed using capital `S`
- Suppressing a lot of one-to-many associations while keeping the opposite many-to-one in the EDMX model
- Extending a common interface in a few entities that share the same column names. This was originally done in a partial extension file, now it is done in the original model class
- Renaming some relationship properties to a readable name

Now I have ended up with a good DbContext that looks like the following (example given for just a few entities)

```
public class ContosoModel {
    public virtual DbSet<SezioneA> sezione_a { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SezioneD> sezione_d { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SezioneE> sezione_e { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SezioneF> sezione_f { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SezioneH> sezione_h { get; set; }



    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SezioneAMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SezioneDMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SezioneEMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SezioneFMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SezioneGMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SezioneHMap());

    }
}

public partial class SezioneA : IStandardColumns
{

    public bool IsValid(bool isStornoContabile)
    {
        if (isStornoContabile)
        {
            return A54a != "4";
        }
        else
        {
            return A54a != "2" && A54a != "3";
        }
    }


    public string A01 { get; set; }
    public string A01a { get; set; }
    public string A01b { get; set; }
    public string A02 { get; set; }
    public string A03 { get; set; }
    public string A11 { get; set; }
    public string A12 { get; set; }
    public string A12a { get; set; }
    public string A12b { get; set; }
    public string A12c { get; set; }
    public string A21 { get; set; }
    public string A22 { get; set; }
    public string A23 { get; set; }
    public string A24 { get; set; }
    public string A25 { get; set; }
    public string A31 { get; set; }


public partial class SezioneA : ISharedColumns
{

    public string A01 { get; set; }
    public string A01a { get; set; }
    public string A01b { get; set; }
    public string A02 { get; set; }
    public string A03 { get; set; }
    public string A11 { get; set; }
    public string A12 { get; set; }
    public string A12a { get; set; }
    public string A12b { get; set; }
    public string A12c { get; set; }
    public string A21 { get; set; }
    public string A22 { get; set; }
    public string A23 { get; set; }
    public string A24 { get; set; }
    public string A25 { get; set; }
    public string A31 { get; set; }

    [...plenties more...]
}


    public SezioneAMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.progA, t.utente });

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.A01)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(13);

        this.Property(t => t.A01a)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(2);

        this.Property(t => t.A01b)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(11);
    }
```

And so on...

When I try to start the application, using Mysql settings backed by Web.xml, I get an error about entity types that really **do not belong** to my context

Here is web.xml

```
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <!--codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">-->
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

<add name="connString"
     connectionString="Server=HOST;Database=DB;Uid=root;Pwd=root;Allow Zero Datetime=True;CharSet=latin1;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=45"
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

### And the error is.....

```
Com.Contoso.Model.Expression: : EntityType 'Expression' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Com.Contoso.Model.ElementInit: : EntityType 'ElementInit' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Com.Contoso.Model.MemberBinding: : EntityType 'MemberBinding' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Com.Contoso.Model.MemberInfo: : EntityType 'MemberInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Com.Contoso.Model.SwitchCase: : EntityType 'SwitchCase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Com.Contoso.Model.CatchBlock: : EntityType 'CatchBlock' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Expressions: EntityType: EntitySet 'Expressions' is based on type 'Expression' that has no keys defined.
ElementInits: EntityType: EntitySet 'ElementInits' is based on type 'ElementInit' that has no keys defined.
MemberBindings: EntityType: EntitySet 'MemberBindings' is based on type 'MemberBinding' that has no keys defined.
MemberInfoes: EntityType: EntitySet 'MemberInfoes' is based on type 'MemberInfo' that has no keys defined.
SwitchCases: EntityType: EntitySet 'SwitchCases' is based on type 'SwitchCase' that has no keys defined.
CatchBlocks: EntityType: EntitySet 'CatchBlocks' is based on type 'CatchBlock' that has no keys defined.
```

Stack trace:

```
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate() +320
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo) +588
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +138
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +196
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +276
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +791
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +52
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +193
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +58
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +141
   System.Linq.Queryable.Cast(IQueryable source) +47
   Com.Contoso.NewsManager.FindAllValid() in NewsManagerImpl.cs:16
```

Question is straight: how do I solve that stuff? Do I need to paste additional information?

Additional info:

- Such entity names do not exist at all in my context
- Despite some non-normalized tables, all have a primary key, and the mapping file **contains** the `HasKey` call

Update:
This may be caused by an irregular relationship mapping. I can only think that `HasRequired`/`HasOptional`/`WithMany`, etc., take a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`. I am investigating more and will post additional code if something out of place is found

Comment: The `Com.Contoso.Model` looks fishy. What is `Contoso` doing in your project?

Comment: `Com.Contoso.Model` is a redacted namespace.

Comment: Actually the problem is that EF in its stack trace makes no mention of the offending entity. If the problem is related to a faulty lambda, mentioning where those `Expression`s are references would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why this happened, but I got my problem solved.

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>();
```

I correctly guessed that this had something to do with LINQ-related classes, maybe because of a built-in convention? I don't know. But definitely the offending entity name `Contoso.Model.Expression` was totally incorrect.